# I don't understand [Bind(Exclude="ID")] in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller

I'm really confused by this... still.

I asked a similar question to this a while before, but i'll ask it even simpler now.

I see this in a lot of samples and tutorials. How could you put [Bind(Exclude="ID")] on an entire Model, and expect to do Edits on the model?  If you get pack all the properties of a model on a POST but not the ID, then how do you know which ID to edit?

Even if i'm using ViewModels... i'm probably creating them without IDs.  So in that case... also... how do I know which ID was updated on an Edit?

Yes, i understand that there is a "security" element to this. People can hijack the ID... so we need to keep people from updating the value during a POST.  But... what is the correct way to handle edits then? What's common practice?

I feel like i'm missing something VERY trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MVC requests are processed by the model binder when the client makes a request. If you include models on your controllers then, as far as I'm aware, you actually have to specify the model you wish to bind to by prefixing your arguments with the model name (unless you only have one argument which is the model)

```
SomeModel_ID
```

Now, in some cases you might want to exclude certain properties from being bound to because they pose a security risk, which you seem to be happy with as a concept. We will exclude ID on the model, preventing any client request from posting this value in plain text.

Now why might we exclude an entire model? Well not all controller arguments are pre-processed by a model binder. RedirectToAction for example does not pass through the model binder, so it is conceivable in this instance for you to create a new model in a POST controller action, and redirect to a GET controller action, passing along a sanitised model. That model cannot be populated by the client, but we are free to populate it ourselves on the server side.

The only time I bind to a model is when I have a view model and an associated editor for that model. This makes it really easy to inject a common editor into a page and to encapsulate those properties. If you have to exclude certain properties from being bound to I would argue that you are doing it wrong.

## Update

Following your comments I think I can see why you might be confused. The model bind excluder prevents the client from ever setting a model property. If you need this property to do your updating then you simply can't exclude it. What this does mean then is that the user could potentially post back any ID. In this case you should check that the user has permission to be modifying any objects or database records associated with this ID before serving the requested update. **Validating the arguments is a manual process**. You can use data annotations for validating inputs, but this isn't likely to help very much with access permissions. It's something you should be checking for manually at some stage.

Comment: Yes, so we are excluding the ID on the model "preventing any client request from positing this value in plain text".  So now... how do we know which record to update? How can we pass the ID during the post in an un-hijackable way if we want to update a record?

Comment: You don't. It's not designed to safeguard you against posting back malformed values. It's a binary condition. You are either allowed to post it back or you are not. If you need to post back an ID then it is your responsibility to check it in the controller, and you obviously need to allow it to be posted.

Comment: So in other words... i shouldn't be doing a bind exclude on the ID if i'm doing an edit.  I should instead, make sure that the ID belongs to the logged in user before doing the update.. or... maybe stick it in the session during the HttpGet and compare it during the HttpPost to make sure its the same ID. Am i thinking correctly?

Comment: Yes, this is absolutely correct... I should probably mention I am not a fan of sessions though. They aren't RESTful for one (which might not be a concern for you), but they can become out of sync in certain situations, like say your permission is revoked while you are editing... Some people will find a session implementation with database permissions as a fallback perfectly acceptable. Most applications require sessions for sensible authentication anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You know the ID because it's passed to you through the page address. So:

```
http://yoursite.com/admin/users/edit/20
```

Will populate your ID parameter with `20`. If it's used in a POST (ie, the information is filled in), just manually fill in the ID field and pass it to the database controller in whatever manner you have devised.

This is also immune to (trivial) hijacks because if they were to write some other ID besides 20, they wouldn't be updating the user with ID 20 now would they? :)

Comment: I don't see how this is immune.  You can start out doing a HttpGet to Edit record 20.  Then, you can do an HttpPost to the same url, except change the 20 to 21.  Now you've updated another record, haven't you?

Comment: Yes, but you haven't circumvented anything. It would be like you manually opened 21 and updated that; all server-side security specific to use 21 will still kick in.